# Poisson distribution question

Tags: poisson-distribution, approximation

An airline has found that the number of people booked on flights who do not arrive at the airport follows a Poisson distribution at the rate  of 2% per flight.For a flight with 146 seats ,150 are sold .Use a suitable approximation to find the probability that there are sufficient seats for everyone who arrives .
My working -
X~Po(2.92) 
Find Probability ,X≥4 
Or 1-P(X= 0,1,2,3)
Equals 0.3348 using Poisson distribution .
Actual answer is 0.353 
Where did I mess up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 150 *sold,* shouldn't the Poisson rate be 2% of 150, which is 3.0. Where did you get 2.92? (Not *much* of a difference, but just asking.)

If $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(3),$ then $P(X \ge 4) = 1 - P(X \le 3) = 0.3527681 \approx 0.353,$ using R. I'll leave the 'suitable approximation' part to you.

```
1-ppois(3,3)
[1] 0.3527681
```

Comment: Ahh ,I took 148 instead ,how silly